# SQL query statement in excel sheet

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oracle

I am having a SQL query of the form:

```
Update TableName Set TaskStatus=xxx where TaskID=xx;
```

I have this SQL query in my C# code.

In an excel file, under B cell, I have a set of statements like Rejected, Completed, Closed and so on. My C# code reads those cells and takes appropriate actions. For example, if it reads Completed, then the below query gets executed:

```
Update TableName Set TaskStatus=Completed where TaskID=xx;
```

My problem is, in a cell, I am having the value Can't Complete. When my code reads this cell and merges this into the query,

```
 Update TableName Set TaskStatus=Can't Complete where TaskID=xx;
```

it throws an error stating that "quotes should be closed" 
It is assuming the quote in Can't as a SQL keyword or SQL quotation. How do I get over this?

Comment: You need to quote and escape the value, i.e. `Update TableName Set TaskStatus='Can''t Complete' where TaskID=xx;` - surround with single quotes and double any single quotes within the string. Where's the code that assembles the SQL - can you do this? Actually if your query is in your C# code you should be using a parameterized query instead so you can pass the value to Oracle without inserting it into your string.

Comment: @Rup it works...y didnt u post it as an answer?? i would hav accepted it..

Comment: Posted as a comment because I wasn't sure if you were generating the SQL in Excel or in your C# code - I probably just didn't read the question well enough. However you should use the parameterized query in Csabo's answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `'` with `''`. The quotes define a text, so your code opens, but doesnt close the text 'area' by inserting `Can't`.

Comment: hi..am getting an error "quoted string not properly terminated"..all i did was to change the text as CAN'''T COMPLETE in the cell in excel sheet

Comment: actually, only two quotes is enough...Can''t complete....three quotes does not work :)

Comment: oh sorry, i typed three quotes and it need to be two. (The first will escape the following)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK using parameterized SQL command solve this problem, sincs SqlParameter objects do the excaping for you in these situations. Something like this in your code should solve your problem:

```
string sql = "Update TableName Set TaskStatus=@status where TaskID=@id;";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("status", status_excel_call_value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", your_task_id);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Also this is safer as stop injection